# Screen blank after upgrading to 22.04, no bios information

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, hardware-failure, graphics

I have recently upgraded from Lubuntu 20.04. to 22.04. The problem is that now when I start the PC, I get blank screen. The system was working well, and then I had a kernel update. I would do the reinstall, but the biggest problem is when I power on my laptop, it doesn't even show the bios or anything,, just black screen turns on (I can see it is turned on, there is light). So, I would like to ask for assistance, as I use this PC for work and it is very urgent. Also, once I just tried restarting, and eventually it showed the screen where I enter the encryption password. Now it doesn't help as much as I restart it.

My laptop model is Lenovo V110-15AST. I tried booting to novo button, but it didn't work. Also no signs or anything, just blank screen with backlight. It happened once already, but after turning the laptop on and off after 3 times it booted into Lenovo sign and everything worked normally. I have also replaced the BIOS battery.

Comment: I am confused you indicated you were unable to boot into your OS then you said after you turned it on and off 3x the system worked normally.

Comment: `it doesn't even show the bios` how are you trying to get into BIOS?

Comment: @Ramhound - I think OP is saying this has happened before.

Comment: Yes, this has happened before, sorry to have missed to point out that. But after a few minutes in the third restart, it just started loading.

Comment: In regards to bios, I tried pressing Fn+f2, only f2, Fn+f12 and only f12. None of these booted bios. I also tried booting to novo button, also nothing.

Comment: Also to add, the screen does "turn on", I can see the light in the background, but it is black

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the disk drive before starting the laptop?

Comment: I am trying it at the moment, will inform you how it went? Do you have any suggestions what I should do after?

Comment: I have disconnected the drive and started it, the screen is still the same

Comment: @JoãozinhoRamos - That suggests a hardware failure

Comment: @JoãozinhoRamos I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "see the light in the background, but it is black" - do you mean that the text/image that would normally be there is still there, if you look at it from a different direction, but the backlight seems to be off?